# Find string that isn't proceeded by other string

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012, regex-negation, findall

I'm trying to come up with the right Regex for Visual Studio's Find All feature, but am having a really hard time. I have the following strings:

String A:

```
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.nope.method(data) #");
```

String B:

```
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.KeyPhrase.otherMethod(data) #");
```

String C:

```
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.something.anything.KeyPhrase.otherMethod(data) #");
```

This regex should only match **String A**. Here's what I thought would work:

```
(ClientTemplate).*~(KeyPhrase)
```

I need to match a string that has "ClientTemplate" in it and does not proceed with "KeyPhrase".

EDIT: *I really screwed this one up. I meant the opposite of what I said:*

#### What regex will match only **String A**?

Comment: If you want a regex that matches B and C but not A, you can use this: 

    ClientTemplate.*KeyPhrase

Is this what you want? Or do you want what the title of your question suggests?

Comment: When you say "a string that has "ClientTemplate" in it" do you mean you wan the whole line, or some other section of the sting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a pattern like this

`ClientTemplate.*KeyPhrase`

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3a1vv)

Or if you want a string that is **NOT** proceeded by `KeyPhrase` you could use a negative lookahead like this

`ClientTemplate(?!.*KeyPhrase.*$).*$`

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3a202)

Comment: My apologies. I did mean **NOT** proceeded by `KeyPhrase`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The question did an about-face on me, so the real answer is at the bottom.  I'm leaving the original because it seems less confusing that way and because I think most of the discussion is still helpful even if the regex isn't.

---

Assuming you're using the regex in pre-2013 Visual Studio (I know you tagged it [visual-studio-2012](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012), but many new users mistakenly add the `visual-studio*` tags when they're really talking about regexes in their code), your regex seems to work if remove the `~`:

```
(ClientTemplate).*(KeyPhrase)
```

The `~(...)` construct is equivalent to a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  You said you want to match lines that **do** contain the key phrase, so you need to *include* it in the regex, not exclude it.  (That's why I removed the [regex-negation](/questions/tagged/regex-negation) tag.)

However, I would go with something more deterministic, like this:

```
ClientTemplate\("\#=[^"]*\.KeyPhrase\.[^"]*"\)
```

I tested this in Visual Studio 2008 and it matches strings B and C, but not A.

---

EDIT:  Turns out this was a negation task after all.  Here's a regex that matches string A and doesn't match strings B and C:

```
<ClientTemplate\("\#= Namespace(\.~(KeyPhrase>):i)*\(data\) \#"\);
```

`:i` is roughly equivalent to `\w+`, the traditional regex for a word in Perl-derived flavors.  The lookahead checks that whatever follows the dot is not `KeyPhrase` before it permits `:i>` to consume it.  The `<` before `ClientTemplate` and the `>` after `KeyPhrase` and `:i` are word boundaries; they make sure you're matching only whole words.

Comment: No problem.  Was I at least right to assume you're using this in VS's search box?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My apologies for not explicitly saying so.

Comment: Actually, my question originally had the tags `find` and `findall`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following strings in a file named 'my_file'

```
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.nope.method(data) #");
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.nope.method(data) #");
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.KeyPhrase.otherMethod(data) #");
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.something.anything.KeyPhrase.otherMethod(data) #");
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.something.anything.KeyPhraze.otherMethod(data) #");
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.something.anything.KeyPHRAZE.otherMethod(data) #");
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.something.anything.KeyPHR?ZE.otherMethod(data) #");
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.something.anything.keyphrase.otherMethod(data) #");
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.something.anything.keyphrase.otherMethod(data) #");
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.something.anything.slkjfiowe.otherMethod(data) #");
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.something.anything.dkjsehtw8.otherMethod(data) #");
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.something.anything.11185.otherMethod(data) #");
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.so...................
```

Command Line

```
 grep  'other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.nope.method(data) #");' '/root/Desktop/my_file'
```

Output

```
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.nope.method(data) #");
other.things.go.here.ClientTemplate("#= Namespace.sub.nope.method(data) #");
```

The command line print anything that similar to string A.

**Regex Pattern can simply be something like this**

```
grep '^other.*go.here.ClientTemplate.*nope.method(data) #");' 'my_file'
```

Comment: If I'm reading the question correctly, the regex should match several of your other sample strings in addition to the first two.

Comment: The user has made an edit saying "What regex will match only String A?". As a result that is how i understood it explicitly focusing on this piece of statement.